# How to Stop Jboss 7.0.0 server using ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, jboss

I have jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final and i am trying to stop the jboss server using ant,my build.xml is

```
   <project name = "stop-jboss" default="stop-jboss">
<target name = "stop-jboss">
<echo>Stop Jboss</echo>
<exec executable = "C:\Testing_jboss\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final\bin\jboss-admin.bat">
<arg value="--connect />
<arg value="--command=:shutdown" />
</exec>
<echo>| J B O S S S T O P P E D |</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

But it doesn't work.What is the solution for this?

Comment: You are calling shutdown.bat on Linux. Not very bright idea. call shutdown.sh instead.

Comment: Sry my build.xml is as follows,

Comment: <project name="stop-jboss" default="stop-jboss">
<target name="stop-jboss">
<echo>"Stop Jboss"</echo>
<exec executable="C:\Testing_jboss\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/shutdown.bat">
</exec>
<echo>| J B O S S S T O P P E D |</echo>
</target>
</project>

Comment: When i execute the above code it shows "Cannot find the file specified".What should i do to stop the jboss 7.0 server using ant build.xml?

Comment: @Kadhar Hussain Was my anwwer useful? If you up-vote and accept useful answers people will be more motivated to help you.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand that&that doesn't work,I am still trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [ant exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) documentation:

> Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One
>   normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd using the
>   /c switch.
>
> ```
> <target name="help">
>   <exec executable="cmd">
>     <arg value="/c"/>
>     <arg value="ant.bat"/>
>     <arg value="-p"/>
>   </exec>
> </target>
> ```

Another option is to check what command is executed in shutdown.bat and call this command from build.xml